Segfault while removing characters from a vector
I want to remove the current character and the previous character from a vector if it matches a specified character. The code works for alphabetic characters like a, b, c. But, if I want to remove multiple characters like *, the code gives a segmentation fault.
Any suggestions?
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    
    vector<char> v;
    vector<char>::iterator it;
    
    string s= "abcdef*gh*i";
    
    
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        v.push_back(s[i]);
        cout << v[i] <<" ";
    }
    cout <<"\n";
    
    for (it = v.begin(); it!= v.end(); it++)
    {
        if(*it == '*'){
        v.erase(it);
        v.erase(it-1);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i< v.size(); i++)
        cout << v[i]<<" ";
    
    return 0;
}


After using erase() your iterator is invalid.

The absolutely simplest way to "erase" elements from a vector, is actually to not erase them. Instead it's to copy everything that should not be erased to a brand new vector.

As for the problem with erase, you need to save what it returns and use it.

Your code also need to add a check for the first character being a '*'.

Are you trying to specifically use vector for this operation? When you do this, a new vector is allocated, the old one is copied to the new one minus the erased element, and the old iterator is invalidated so you no longer have access to the old vector. Is that what you want to do?

Not quite. Usually after erasing nothing is reallocated because reallocation can take quite a bit of time. Typically the item erased is simply written over by the items that come after it in the vector. The iterator is invalidated because it no longer references the item that it previously did. That said, the implementation could do just about anything so long as it doesn't violate the specified end outcome and complexity rules.

Be careful with code like v.erase(it-1); If the iterator refers to the first item in the vector there will be no it-1 to erase. That would be bad.

I realize you asked specifically about vectors, but I decided to use strings because that's the natural thing to do for sequences of characters.
The first thing to do is to figure out how you'll test your solution.  I came up with this:
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

void test(std::string_view original, std::string_view expected) {
    auto x = std::string(original.data(), original.size());
    treatStarAsBackspace(x);
    assert(x == expected);
}

int main() {
    test("", "");
    test("abc", "abc");
    test("ab*c", "ac");
    test("*", "");
    test("ab*cd*ef*", "ace");
    test("*abc", "abc");
    test("abc*",  "ab");
    test("abc***", "");
    return 0;
}

There are two things to note about the problem:

chars are cheap to copy.  They're small and don't have constructors or destructors.  So there's not much harm if we copy a few more than absolutely necessary.  This makes for a simpler algorithm.

At each step in the process, the resulting string will never be longer than the original.  Thus it's possible to process the characters in place.  You don't have to do it that way, but it may be convenient.


With that in mind, I came up with this:
// Modifies the string in place as though each asterisk is an instruction to
// delete the previous character.
void treatStarAsBackspace(std::string &s) {
    auto target = s.begin();
    for (auto source = s.cbegin(); source != s.cend(); ++source) {
        if (*source == '*') {
            if (target != s.begin()) --target;
        } else {
            *target++ = *source;
        }
    }
    // The desired result is now the range `s.begin()` up to
    // `target`, so we have to erase anything beyond that.
    s.erase(target, s.end());
}


Especially in a case like this, where you're copying the data anyway, @some Programmer Dude is right: the easiest way to deal with this is almost certainly to filter the data as you copy it.
    std::string s= "abcdef*gh*i";
    std::string v;

    std::cout << s << "\n";

    for (std::size_t source = 0; source < s.size()-1; source++) {
        if (s[source+1] != '*')
            v.push_back(s[source]);
        else
            ++source;
    }

    if (s.back() != '*')
        v.push_back(s.back());

    std::cout << v << "\n";

Result:
abcdef*gh*i
abcdegi


Read / Write pair
Coming back to this to offer a solution not presented. For any indexed sequence (aka ordered sequence, not necessarily contiguous), where you know every modification will reduce the length of the sequence (by, for your example, simply removing elements), then all you need is a read/write pair of pointers (or iterators).
That is:

a read iterator to scan ahead
a write iterator to write changes

Lookahead space
Since your modification requires a single lookahead, then a single read-but-not-written buffer is useful for intermediate storage (making this an O(1) space addition). Again, since you are dealing with shrinkage, you need not actually keep this as a separate buffer, it could be just another iterator into the sequence! (If you do that, though, make sure to keep in mind the potential for overlap!) For a single character, a separate read-but-not-yet-written character is fine.
Problems must be complete and specific
Your description of the problem leaves it unclear what leading and multiple consecutive stars mean.
The following assumes that:

any number of stars in sequence is equivalent to a single star(instead of the more complex “abCD**efg” --> “abefg” possibility,or even the simple stars-can-eat-stars possibility), and
any leading stars simply disappear.

The read / write filter
// The interface here is the long-time Standard C++ kind of way to access an
// ordered sequence: provide iterators to the beginning (inclusive) and to
// the end (exclusive).
//
// It also uses the long-standing C++ Standard Library filter-modify design
// where it returns the NEW end of the sequence, but does not ERASE any elements;
// It only moves things around.

template <typename Iterator>
Iterator remove_x_star( Iterator begin, Iterator end )
{
    // Empty sequences get no love
    if (begin == end) return end;

    auto read  = begin;
    auto write = begin;

    // All leading stars are to be eliminated.
    while (*read == '*')
        if (++read == end) // If we hit the end, then we're done.
            return write;  // Return the new end.

    // Initialize our one-character buffer
    // (Observe that c cannot be a star!)
    auto c = *read++;

    // While there are unprocessed characters...
    while (read != end)
    {
        // If we find a star, we want to move to the next possible
        // sequence, resetting our one-character buffer as appropriate
        //   ...x**...  -->  ...x**...
        //       r                 cr
        if (*read == '*')
        {
            // (This should look familiar)
            while (*read == '*')
                if (++read == end)
                    return write;
            // Restock our one-character buffer and update our read
            c = *read++;
        }

        // Otherwise, there is no star and we should write our
        // one-character buffer to its final destination, restock the
        // buffer with the next available character, and update our
        // read and write iterators.
        //   ....cx.  -->  c...cx.
        //   w   cr         w   cr
        else
        {
            *write++ = c;
            c = *read++;
        }
    }

    // Don't forget that one-character waiting to be copied
    *write++ = c;

    // The end of the written (copied) characters == end of the new sequence
    return write;
}

I know that looks long, but if you get rid of all the commentary you’ll recognize just how simple the code actually is. Again, the idea is: scan ahead, keeping track of potential characters to write, and write as appropriate.
Helper functions for the win
Now we can wrap our desired functionality into a little helper function, which takes any container and applies the above algorithm AND actually resizes the container with the Container::erase( it, end ) method.
template <typename Container>
void delete_x_stars( Container & xs )
{
    xs.erase(
        remove_x_star( xs.begin(), xs.end() ), // new end
        xs.end() );  // old end
}

Main program
Finally we can play with it.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//using namespace std;
// Get into the habit of not dragging an entire namespace into your code.
// It is totally worth your time to get used to just typing “std::”
// (or whatever the correct namespace is) in front of objects and functions.
// It is easy and gets you to better learn when you _shouldn’t_ do it.

// Here's a helper to make testing easy
void test( std::string s )
{
    std::cout << "\n[" << s << "]\n";  // print before
    delete_x_stars( s );
    std::cout << "[" << s << "]\n";    // and after
}

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "abcdef*gh*i";

    // We can use a vector (or any indexed sequence) to play with the string
    std::vector <char> v( s.begin(), s.end() );

    std::cout << "[";  for (char c : v) std::cout << c;  std::cout << "]\n";  // before
    delete_x_stars( v );
    std::cout << "[";  for (char c : v) std::cout << c;  std::cout << "]\n";  // after

    // We can even use (a copy of) our original string
    test( s );

    // And we can verify that it works for special cases,
    // such as leading and consecutive stars
    test( "*ab**c" );
    test( "***" );
    test( "a***" );
    test( "ab**" );
    test( "*b**" );
    test( "*b" );
    test( "*" );
    test( "" );
}

Recap
Not to over-overstate anything, but again the idea is to have a pointer/index/iterator for the read position and another for the write position. This works with all kinds of containers, as long as the container is ordered. (So, for example, bad for a hash map, since elements are not relatively ordered, but great for vectors and deques and files and strings etc since their elements are ordered.)
Even simple array-indexing stuff (like playing with char* strings in C) are very easy to do with this basic read-filter-write kind of transform.
There really is a pretty big learning curve to programming, but you just need to wrap your head around it. Keep going at it and it’ll get easier (and more interesting)! 

  string s ;
  cin >> s ;
  stack<char> temp ;
  for(auto it : s){
    if(it=='*' and temp.size() > 0){
        temp.pop();
    }
    else{
        temp.push(it);
    }
  }
  string ans = "";
  while(temp.size()){
    char ch = temp.top();
    ans+=ch;
    temp.pop();
  }
  reverse(ans.begin(),ans.end());
  cout << ans << endl;  


You should explain what the problem is, what you suggested code is doing, and how it solves the problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you want to delete elements from a vector or an array, it's advisable to iterate from the end of the loop. This approach helps maintain the integrity of the indexes of all elements in your vector, array, etc.
For example:
When iterating from the beginning of the loop:
vector container = [a,b,c,d]

If you erase, let's say, 'b':
Your 'c' is now indexed as the second element, and thus the integrity is compromised. Here, it's updated and then iterated.
However, when iterating from the end of the loop:
vector container = [a,b,c,d]

If you erase 'b' again:
Your 'c' remains indexed as the second element, preserving integrity. This is because 'c' is iterated first, and then updated. This method makes a significant difference!
Here is your program code fixed:
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

vector<char> v;
vector<char>::iterator it;

string s= "abcdef*gh*i";


for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
    v.push_back(s[i]);
    cout << s[i] <<" ";
}
cout <<"\n";



for (it = v.end(); it >= v.begin();  it--)
{
    if(*it == 'i'){
    v.erase(it);
    v.erase(it-1);
    }
}
for(int i=0; i< v.size(); i++)
    cout << v[i]<<" ";

return 0;
}


it >= v.begin(); should be it != v.begin(); But the point is moot as v.erase(it); invalidates it, making it unusable to safely remove it-1 on the next line (assuming there is a it-1 that can be removed).
